# java memory profiler?

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please recommend a Java profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762/please-recommend-a-java-profiler)

I developed a java appliation in j2sdk1.4.2_18,Eclipse3.1,I want to analysis the memory leak in my application.There are some profiler software available to analysis the memory usage.but,they are all java version specific.is there any profiler available for my java version?pls give me link to download..

thanks in advance

Comment: Memory leak? In a garbage collecting language? Is such thing even possible unless the memory leak is in the JVM itself? By the way, JDK 1.4 does have memory leaks at least in the NIO packge.

Comment: Garbage collection makes memory leaks unlikely but not impossible: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/05/0816_GuptaPalanki/. For example, they can happen by adding objects to a Collection and not removing them after they are no longer necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java 1.4 is *ancient*, [2 years past its EOL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) for the standard release. You have two options:

- Buy very expensive [business support](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/java-for-business-071123.html) from Oracle
- Simply run the app on a modern Java 6 VM and profile there with current tools.

Since Java VMs generally have very good downwards compatibility with older apps, this should not be a problem (you may encounter some version dependent bugs, but not many). Running on Java 1.4 will only cause more and more problems over time, and you will have to make the switch eventually.

Comment: I am surprised it hasn't been EOLed for longer as Java 5.0 has been EOL for over a year now. IMHO, Your suggestion is the best approach.

Comment: BTW: I have tried to get a quote for business support for Java from Oracle and have been on a waiting list for over six months to be told what the support arrangement/costs will be when they have worked it out for themselves. :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of Java profilers available: http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers

Answer (score 1):

I personally have been using [YourKit](http://yourkit.com/) for some time and I love it. It is a commercial product, but there is a [trial download](http://yourkit.com/download/index.jsp) on the Web site so you can try it out first.

(I have no connection to the company other than as a customer.)

Comment: Recent versions of YourKit only support Java 6 & 7. I prefer it too.

Comment: True, but there's a tab on the page I linked to for an older version of YourKit that does support Java 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a free profiler, look at [Netbeans profiler](http://profiler.netbeans.org/docs/help/5.5/vms.html).
If you are willing to pay, try [Yourkit](http://www.yourkit.com/download/index.jsp)